# How to give a bounty to one or more users directly?

Tags: feature-request, reputation, bounty

In Stack Overflow an anonymous user gave me 50 points of reputation:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5905822/function-to-find-the-nth-digit-of-pi/28000950#28000950

Can I do that on MSE? If so, how?

Comment: put a bounty on a question where the user answered (preferable the answer you wish to reward). And award them the bounty. Isn't it?

Comment: You can find several useful links with basic information about bounties here: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/tags/bounty/info And you can also have a look at older questions here on meta tagged ([meta-tag:bounty]).

Comment: [Not really anonymous](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/5905822/revisions). You can see who awarded the bounty by hovering over the bounty icon next to your answer.

Comment: Thank you all! I think I got it.